# AngularJS Drag and Drop

Tags: angularjs

If I have a JSON like below ..

```
$scope.pools = [    {id: 1, poolName : 'Pool1', env : 'Env1', executionMode: 'Both',
        modelets: [{id: 'm1', name : 'MM1', status : 'active', capacity : '1 GB'},
                   {id: 'm2', name : 'MM2', status : 'active', capacity : '1 GB'},
                   {id: 'm3', name : 'MM3', status : 'active', capacity : '1 GB'}]},
    {id: 2, poolName : 'Pool2', env : 'Env2', executionMode: 'Both',
        modelets: [{id: 'm4', name : 'MR1', status : 'active', capacity : '1 GB'},
                   {id: 'm5', name : 'MR2', status : 'active', capacity : '1 GB'}]
    }
];
```

and I have to drag and drop the modelet from one pool to another. for example, if I am dragging m3 from pool1 to and dropping it into modelets of pool2, then m3 should be removed from pool1.modelets and it should be added into pool2.modelets and vice-versa.

Note : I am trying it using http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/

Please provide me effective solution. Thanks in adnavce.

Comment: After drag and drop, modelets data for pools are not changing in correct manner.

Comment: Check the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5dm6v9fr/7/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got something which is working fine in this case ...
We need to do below changes in draggable element.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="pool.modelets" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}" ng-hide="!modelet.name">{{modelet.name}}</div>
```

[updated fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/5dm6v9fr/8/) is working fine.